# Using PyInstaller with Python 2.7 - includes modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have a small python program where strucuture looks like this:

```
project
 |-controllers
     |-controller1.py
     |-controller2.py
     |- ......
 |-help
     |-helpfile1.help
     |-helpfile2.help
     |-.......
 |-utils.py
 |-main.py
```

Of course I am using venv to test my Python code with Python 2.7 version...
I've installed into my venet: PyInstaller and how I use it:

```
pyinstaller --clean -F --distpath "/path/to/compressed/mainfile/" --add-data "utils.py:utils.py" --add-data "help/*.help:help" --add-data "controllers/*.py:controllers" main.py
```

...if I call the compressed main "python" file I got an error the not found anything as controller ot help.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'controller1'
```

I've created a another venv where Python version is: 3.6. Installed PyInstaller create a compressed main "python" file...and with this version (Python 3.6) works fine!

So I not understand wha I do wrong? Why not includes controllers and help folder content when I use PyInstaller with Python2.7
I've tried to find solution on the internet but I couldn't :(

has anybody any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @eyllanesc! Thanks for your modification....and...do you have any ideo what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: @ahBanhidy! Do you have the same version of pyinstaller installed on python2.7 and python3.6 virtuanenv?

Comment: Hello @krishna! Good idea to check it.I've check it and I am using PyInstaller 3.5 in both venv.